# AD user object properties altered by non-English ADUC

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, localization

We are running a hybrid Azure AD environment. We have a number of scripts and API's used to sync our AD user objects with other software. We are encountering issues where certain user object properties are not being returned by Get-ADUser commands in PowerShell (like address, state and country).

After some trial and error, we discovered that if a user object was updated using ADUC in another language (French in our case), the updated objects would return null values for certain properties. By simply returning to the user object with ADUC in English and clicking on Apply, the properties are once again exportable via Get-ADUser.

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue, either by modifying our scripts or applying some sort of AD schema update ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls try similar cmdlet as-below without changing the orginal data in Active Directory?

$pso = New-PSSessionOption -Culture "fr-fr" -MaximumReceivedObjectSize 10MB
New-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -SessionOption $pso

Get-ADUser